# Run java function in thread

Tags: multithreading, java-8

Is there way to run function/method in its own thread?

I have two use cases for this right now. One is that I have a `Consumer<T>` that is passed in. I want to run this on its own thread as it will take a long time to finish.

The other use case that I have is that I have a number of functions in the same class that I want to run in their own threads individually (one thread per function). These functions need access to private data in their class's state.

Is there a way to do this in java?

**Update:** For what its worth, I know about the "normal" way of doing this, either by extending Thread, or implementing runnable. However, in both of these cases those approaches don't work.

**Update 2:**
Implementing `Runnable` won't work as the class has a number of different methods that all have to be independently "run" on their own threads. Given that there are quite a few methods in this class that would need to run threads, this won't work. Since these threads require access to some shared private data, I can't even split each method into its own class (even though that would not map to what I would consider a logical class anyway).

For the case where I have a `Consumer<T>` I can't extend/implement `Thread/Runnable` as I don't control the interface. The method takes a `Consumer<T>` as a parameter, and I need to call it in it's own thread. I suppose here I could create a wrapper class, but then I would have to create (I think) one wrapper class each for `Consumer`, `Function`, etc. And all of this seems rather needless (at least coming from other languages).

**Update 3:** Assume that synchronization is not an issue (data is either immutable, or contention is very low)
I am looking for a better way. Is this clearer?

Comment: Start by reading Java Concurrency in Practice.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Can you be more specific? You just recommended your own book...

Comment: @soandos Coming from the person that actually wrote the book (and is a JDK developer), this means that the question is too-broad and that you're missing the basics of concurrency. Which this book will introduce to you ;)

Comment: Voting to close because the ISBN-13 is 078-5342349603

Comment: @Tunaki, I don't see how its too broad. I have a well defined problem. I know that the "normal" way of doing this is to implement a class that can extend Thread, or implement runnable, but in the cases above this is not possible. What am I missing?

Comment: To give this topic a little push: Please provide some code else the others are right and this topic is way too broad.

Comment: @soandos Please add to the question details about why you think the standard approaches won't work.

Comment: @Flown, didn't add code, but I did add some context. Do you want me to post some dummy classes or is this enough?

Comment: Read the Java Concurrency in Practice book like everybody recommends, I think you will find it very relevant to your problem. This does seem too broad for SO.

Comment: @NathanHughes how is this too broad? I have a very specific question. Can you at least point me at somewhere more specific than "in the book"?

Comment: Your question is basically "how can I have some thread running and tell them what to do later".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that is not at all what I am asking. What I mean is "how can I launch an existing method/or something that acts like a method" in its own thread. I don't want to tell them what to do later, assume all communication and synchronization is already handled. Is that clearer?

Comment: @soandos It's precisely the same thing. The problem you have is that you can't easily tell your thread what you want it to do at the same time you're creating it. So you need a way to break that dependency. The answer to "how can I launch an existing method in its own thread" is: 1) Launch the thread (this is easy). 2) Tell it what to do (this is what you don't know how to do).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz in C++, I'd be looking for `std::thread newThread (myFunc);` Does this exist in java? is it too broad of a thing to ask for?

Comment: @soandos: there are inner classes, lambda expressions and method references. If you’ve heard of at least one of these, your question either, describes a problem for which a simple solution exists or fails to describe what your actual problem with these solutions is. In either case, it’s not a good question.

Comment: @soandos I think dummy code would indeed clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a partial solution for the functions / methods (if they don't need arguments) you can use `Thread`s or an `ExecutorService` and method references.

If you need arguments you will have to write lambda expressions - see the method `t3` and it's start for an example.

```
public class Test {

  public void t1() {
    System.out.println("t1");
  }

  public void t2() {
    System.out.println("t2");
  }

  public void t3(int n) {
    System.out.println("t3:"+n);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Test test = new Test();
    Thread t = new Thread(test::t1);
    t.start();
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    es.submit(test::t2);
    es.submit(() -> test.t3(99));
    es.shutdown();
    es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to extend this if they do need arguments?

Comment: check out `FutureTask` and here is [an example](http://www.journaldev.com/1650/java-futuretask-example-program). Also look into lambdas and new style as an aside. As for the link, there are 3 code snippets. Look at the largest one in the middle and lines 16 and 17

Comment: @soandos I've added an example method with arguments and how you could call this method.